# How do I get the child items of child items?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a database with four tables: `ParentCategory`, `ChildCategory`, `ItemsCategories`, and `Items`. The table named `ItemsCategories` is a join table since a a row in `Item` can listed multiple times in `ChildCategory`. The primary key in all tables is named `ID`. The foreign key column in the `ChildCategory` is `ParentCategoryID` and the foreign keys in `ItemsCategories` are `ItemID` and `ChildCategoryID`.

I need to write a `SELECT` query that when given the `Name` of a `ParentCategory` will return a list of `Items`. The `ParentCategory` table does contain a `Name` field.

I'm not sure where to begin with this one. I can write a `SELECT` To return the `ParentCategory` ID given a category name and I can `JOIN` the tables.

Thanks!

update 1 -

This works...

```
SELECT   Item.Name  
FROM         ParentCategory
            INNER JOIN ChildCategory ON ParentCategory.ID = ChildCategory.ParentCategoryID
            INNER JOIN ItemsCategories ON ChildCategory.ID = ItemsCategories.ChildCategoryId
            INNER JOIN Items ON ItemsCategories.ItemId = items.ID
            WHERE ParentCategory.Name = 'XXX'
```

Comment: Have you tried something?, can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT i.ID
FROM ParentCategory pc
JOIN ChildCategory cc ON cc.ParentCategoryID = pc.ID
JOIN ItemsCategories ic ON ic.ChildCategoryID = cc.ID
JOIN Items i ON ic.ItemID = i.ID
WHERE pc.Name LIKE 'Name'
```

That should get Items ID, but you can easily extend the SELECT list to contain more data from Items table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i've understood your model correctly:

```
SELECT i.ID,i.Name 
FROM ParentCategory pc 
INNER JOIN ChildCategory cc
ON pc.ID = cc.ParentCategoryID
INNER JOIN ItemsCategories ic
ON cc.ID = ic.ChildCategoryID
INNER JOIN Item i
ON ic.ItemID = i.ID
WHERE pc.Name = @ParentCategory
```